# Is there a per target set() method in modern CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to achieve the same behavior as `set()` function in CMake but using targets. Let's assume I have one main CMakeList and two sub-folders with one CMakeList each.

```
Foo CMakeLists.txt :

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
add_subdirectory(Bar)
add_subdirectory(Tox)

add_library(foo STATIC main.cpp)
#command to set UseFeatureA=ON
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar )
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC tox)
```

```
Bar CMakeLists.txt:

add_library(bar PUBLIC bar.cpp)

if(UseFeatureA) #This has to be true
target_sources(bar PRIVATE coolFeatureA.cpp)
endif()
```

```
Tox CMakeLists.txt:

add_library(tox STATIC tox.cpp)

if(UseFeatureA) #This has to be FALSE
target_sources(bar PRIVATE coolFeatureA.cpp)
endif()
```

I have tried  `target_compile_definition()` in `Foo` but I don't know how to retrieve the var in `Bar`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to achieve. Can you try to explain it more, or show an example (perhaps in pseudo-code) of what you want?

Comment: Could you provide some **code** which you already have (which creates Foo, Bar targets and links them with target_link_libraries), and what you want to achieve (in that part you may use pseudo-code)? This would make the question *clear*, and doesn't require the answers to re-invent the code which you already have.

Comment: I believe you are confusing the concept of variables with target properties.  `target_compile_definition( FOO  ...)` sets certain properties (see documentation for command on which properties).  To retrieve those properties use `get_target_property`.  It should be easy to find examples on how to do this.